# Get data from cell in pandas and user it in calculations

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've got a CSV file which I am loading in to a table using pandas.

```
     Rank                   Player  Nat Tot MtchWin-Loss Tie BrkWin-Loss  \
0       1           Novak Djokovic  SRB              5-0             0-0   
1       2            Roger Federer  SUI              1-1             0-1   
2       3              Andy Murray  GBR              0-0             0-0   
3       4             Rafael Nadal  ESP             11-3             2-1   
4       5            Kei Nishikori  JPN              5-0             0-0   
5       6             Milos Raonic  CAN              2-1             1-0   
6       7            Tomas Berdych  CZE              4-1             2-0   
7       8             David Ferrer  ESP             10-2             2-2   
8       9            Stan Wawrinka  SUI              1-1             0-0   
9      10              Marin Cilic  CRO              2-2             1-0   
10     11          Grigor Dimitrov  BUL              3-1             0-0   
11     12          Feliciano Lopez  ESP              5-3             4-1   
12     13             Gilles Simon  FRA              3-2             2-0   
13     14       Jo-Wilfried Tsonga  FRA              2-2             0-1   
14     15             Gael Monfils  FRA              6-2             5-0   
15     16    Roberto Bautista Agut  ESP              4-3             2-2   
16     17           Kevin Anderson  RSA              2-1             1-3   
17     18               John Isner  USA              2-2             2-2   
18     19            Tommy Robredo  ESP              6-5             0-2   
19     20           Ernests Gulbis  LAT              0-2             0-0   
20     21             David Goffin  BEL              1-1             0-0   
21     22             Ivo Karlovic  CRO              1-1             0-0   
22     23             Pablo Cuevas  URU             10-4             4-2   
23     24            Martin Klizan  SVK             10-5             3-1   
24     25           Leonardo Mayer  ARG              4-4             2-1   
25     26    Philipp Kohlschreiber  GER              3-2             3-2   
26     27            Bernard Tomic  AUS              1-1             1-1   
27     28          Richard Gasquet  FRA              0-0             0-0   
28     29            Fabio Fognini  ITA              8-5             3-2   
29     30         Adrian Mannarino  FRA              0-1             0-0   
..    ...                      ...  ...              ...             ...   
170   171               Elias Ymer  SWE              2-2             1-1   
171   172              Renzo Olivo  ARG              2-2             2-1   
172   173               Tommy Haas  GER              0-0             0-0   
173   174          Nicolas Almagro  ESP              8-5             3-2   
174   175                Alex Bolt  AUS              0-0             0-0   
175   176               Mate Delic  CRO              0-0             0-0   
176   177              Liam Broady  GBR              0-0             0-0   
177   178            Maxime Authom  BEL              0-0             0-0   
178   179          Roberto Marcora  ITA              0-0             0-0   
179   180             Marius Copil  ROU              0-1             0-0   
180   181             Lukasz Kubot  POL              0-0             0-0   
181   182         Guilherme Clezar  BRA              0-3             0-1   
182   183    Ruben Ramirez Hidalgo  ESP              0-0             0-0   
183   184            Andrej Martin  SVK              0-0             0-0   
184   185         Andrea Arnaboldi  ITA              0-0             0-0   
185   186            Gerald Melzer  AUT              1-1             2-1   
186   187              Jan Hernych  CZE              0-0             0-0   
187   188           Julian Reister  GER              0-0             0-0   
188   189            Nicolas Jarry  CHI              3-1             1-0   
189   190              Mirza Basic  BIH              0-0             0-0   
190   191         Filippo Volandri  ITA              0-0             0-0   
191   192           Dennis Novikov  USA              0-0             0-0   
192   193          Denys Molchanov  UKR              0-0             0-0   
193   194               Jason Jung  USA              0-0             0-0   
194   195             Luke Saville  AUS              0-0             0-0   
195   196           Evgeny Donskoy  RUS              0-1             0-1   
196   197             Adrian Ungur  ROU              0-0             0-0   
197   198  Hans Podlipnik-Castillo  CHI              1-0             0-0   
198   199          Thomas Fabbiano  ITA              0-1             0-0   
199   200                Tim Puetz  GER              0-0             0-0   

     Tot Aces  Ace/ Mtch Avg  Tot Dbl Flts  DF/ Mtch Avg 1st Srv 1st Srv Won  \
0           9            1.8             7           1.4     62%         74%   
1           9            4.5             2           1.0     59%         68%   
2           0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
3          25            1.8            18           1.3     68%         69%   
4          14            2.8             9           1.8     57%         75%   
5          16            5.3             3           1.0     64%         78%   
6          18            3.6             8           1.6     53%         81%   
7          18            1.5            32           2.7     62%         66%   
8           2            1.0             2           1.0     58%         64%   
9          20            5.0             5           1.3     60%         72%   
10         12            3.0             5           1.3     63%         74%   
11         66            8.3            23           2.9     60%         74%   
12         14            2.8            13           2.6     64%         63%   
13         13            3.3             5           1.3     59%         70%   
14         32            4.0             5           0.6     63%         69%   
15         16            2.3            13           1.9     64%         73%   
16         40           13.3             9           3.0     65%         74%   
17         49           12.3             6           1.5     68%         77%   
18         41            3.7            20           1.8     66%         72%   
19          9            4.5            15           7.5     52%         67%   
20          9            4.5             7           3.5     51%         67%   
21         23           11.5             4           2.0     71%         86%   
22         78            6.5            22           1.8     56%         74%   
23         49            3.1            54           3.4     59%         70%   
24         41            6.8            13           2.2     64%         71%   
25         10            1.7             5           0.8     65%         61%   
26         11            3.7             2           0.7     70%         66%   
27          0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
28         41            2.9            35           2.5     57%         65%   
29          0            0.0             2           2.0     64%         47%   
..        ...            ...           ...           ...     ...         ...   
170        12            3.0             6           1.5     58%         65%   
171         9            2.3            36           9.0     57%         71%   
172         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
173        81            5.8            25           1.8     56%         75%   
174         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
175         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
176         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
177         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
178         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
179         8            8.0             2           2.0     60%         78%   
180         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
181        11            3.7            10           3.3     61%         64%   
182         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
183         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
184         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
185        11            5.5             6           3.0     58%         75%   
186         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
187         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
188        25           12.5            10           5.0     60%         72%   
189         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
190         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
191         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
192         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
193         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
194         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
195         1            1.0             9           9.0     52%         70%   
196         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
197         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   
198         3            3.0             4           4.0     73%         61%   
199         0            0.0             0           0.0      0%          0%   

    2nd Srv Won Srv Gam Won Brk Pts Won Brk Pts Svd Pts Won Ret Srv1st-2nd  \
0           58%         88%         42%         68%                39%-57%   
1           54%         84%         46%         67%                37%-49%   
2            0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
3           57%         82%         43%         57%                36%-58%   
4           62%         92%         49%         80%                39%-62%   
5           62%         90%         25%         50%                26%-46%   
6           52%         82%         47%         68%                37%-49%   
7           54%         78%         47%         61%                40%-56%   
8           50%         59%         25%         46%                41%-47%   
9           49%         74%         43%         58%                26%-43%   
10          49%         85%         38%         79%                35%-48%   
11          54%         82%         42%         65%                28%-50%   
12          47%         68%         56%         63%                31%-56%   
13          58%         87%         31%         78%                26%-45%   
14          53%         82%         42%         68%                31%-51%   
15          48%         80%         53%         62%                29%-53%   
16          47%         83%         55%         68%                35%-47%   
17          56%         91%         25%         75%                26%-39%   
18          52%         82%         42%         65%                32%-48%   
19          32%         50%         33%         50%                29%-39%   
20          55%         76%         38%         69%                38%-52%   
21          43%         88%         22%         25%                21%-45%   
22          54%         82%         49%         63%                32%-47%   
23          48%         76%         43%         63%                31%-49%   
24          50%         81%         23%         65%                31%-57%   
25          52%         67%         48%         51%                35%-54%   
26          47%         73%         38%         58%                33%-52%   
27           0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
28          49%         67%         49%         61%                32%-54%   
29          41%         29%         33%         50%                26%-38%   
..          ...         ...         ...         ...                    ...   
170         50%         69%         38%         60%                30%-55%   
171         51%         79%         27%         62%                29%-51%   
172          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
173         55%         82%         32%         59%                32%-47%   
174          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
175          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
176          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
177          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
178          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
179         56%         77%         43%         40%                36%-39%   
180          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
181         44%         67%         39%         50%                24%-53%   
182          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
183          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
184          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
185         43%         77%         14%         73%                21%-51%   
186          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
187          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
188         62%         86%         38%         75%                25%-43%   
189          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
190          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
191          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
192          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
193          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
194          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
195         52%         79%         18%         70%                28%-42%   
196          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
197          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   
198         39%         60%         17%         43%                22%-45%   
199          0%          0%          0%          0%                  0%-0%   

    Ret Gam Won  
0           46%  
1           33%  
2            0%  
3           38%  
4           42%  
5           12%  
6           30%  
7           42%  
8           33%  
9           15%  
10          25%  
11          20%  
12          31%  
13          13%  
14          24%  
15          26%  
16          26%  
17           8%  
18          27%  
19          16%  
20          32%  
21           8%  
22          25%  
23          25%  
24          21%  
25          36%  
26          32%  
27           0%  
28          31%  
29          13%  
..          ...  
170         23%  
171         17%  
172          0%  
173         22%  
174          0%  
175          0%  
176          0%  
177          0%  
178          0%  
179         23%  
180          0%  
181         22%  
182          0%  
183          0%  
184          0%  
185         11%  
186          0%  
187          0%  
188         11%  
189          0%  
190          0%  
191          0%  
192          0%  
193          0%  
194          0%  
195         14%  
196          0%  
197          0%  
198         11%  
199          0%
```

I'm not sure why it goes on different lines, ideally I want to see it go all the way horizontally but that's not a massive issue. What I want to to be able to do is get certain data from cells based on criteria. For example I've done this to get the 1st Serve Percentage of Novak Djokovic:

```
firstServePecentage = df[["1st Srv"]][df['Player'] == 'Novak Djokovic']
```

This returns:

```
  1st Srv
0     62%
```

As you can see this gets the column and row names. How can I just get the value 62% so I can convert it to a decimal, 0.62, and be able to assign this to a variable that I can use for calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is returned is a Series, if you want just the value:

```
firstServePecentage = df[df['Player'] == 'Novak Djokovic']['1st Srv']
firstServePecentage.values[0]
```

Comment: Thank you. Just incase anyone sees this in the futures and wants to know how to remove the `%` sign and convert to a decimal I did this: `float(df[df['Player'] == 'Novak Djokovic']['1st Srv'].values[0].strip('%'))/100`